# Is it possible to increase Oracle execution plan output indentation?

Tags: oracle, execution-plan

It seems Oracle's execution plan indent each row for just one character. See below image. Is there a setting to increase this value? To me, this is not very readable.

[image]

Comment: You are asking about a tool that displays some data. You want to change the way how the tool displays the data. So you have to tell us which tool you use to display the data. It is not a property of the database you are asking about.

Comment: I use DataGrip, but the result is exactly the same as sqlplus. I guess they use the same mechanism underneath.

Comment: Instead of using `dbms_xplan` package to display the plan, you can write your own (recursive) statement that retrieves the plan from `plan_table` and uses a different number of spaces to indent. Pretty much the way it was done before Oracle introduced `dbms_xplan.display()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PLAN_TABLE for such result as following:

Your statement for generating the execution plan

```
EXPLAIN PLAN 
SET STATEMENT_ID = 'mystatement1'  -- give your statement a meaningful ID so that we can fetch it from PLAN_TABLE using it
    FOR
SELECT
    *
FROM
    ACTIVE_USERS;
```

Now, Fetching the execution plan from PLAN_TABLE

```
SELECT
    ID,
   -- LPAD(' ', LEVEL - 1) -- default format
    LPAD(' ', LEVEL * 2) -- Indentation is done using this
    || OPERATION
    || ' '
    || OPTIONS
    || ' '
    || OBJECT_NAME "Operation",
    OBJECT_NAME   AS "Name"
FROM
    PLAN_TABLE
CONNECT BY PRIOR ID = PARENT_ID
           AND PRIOR STATEMENT_ID = STATEMENT_ID START WITH ID = 0
                AND STATEMENT_ID = 'mystatement2'
ORDER BY
    ID;
```

**Output:**

[image]

You can add more columns into result according to your need and also add more spaces using LPAD in the above query.

Cheers!!